COBOL file creation of DAT file is not successful
I am getting this error below when the COBOL code is run.
'EmployeeFile' is not defined
'EmployeeFile' is not a file name
Here is the COBOL code.
IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
PROGRAM-ID. CreateEmployeeFile.

DATA DIVISION.
FILE SECTION.
FD EmployeeFile
    LABEL RECORDS STANDARD
    VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "EMPLOYEE.DAT"
    DATA RECORD IS EmployeeRecord.
01 EmployeeRecord.
    05 EmployeeID      PIC X(5).
    05 EmployeeName    PIC X(30).
    05 Salary          PIC 9(6)V99.

WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
01 EOF-Switch          PIC X VALUE 'N'.
01 Temp-EmployeeID     PIC X(5).
01 Temp-EmployeeName   PIC X(30).
01 Temp-Salary         PIC 9(6)V99.
01 Counter             PIC 99 VALUE ZERO.
01 Choice              PIC 9 VALUE ZERO.

PROCEDURE DIVISION.
Begin.
    OPEN OUTPUT EmployeeFile
    PERFORM Until-Exit
    CLOSE EmployeeFile
    STOP RUN.

Until-Exit.
    DISPLAY "1. Add Record"
    DISPLAY "2. Exit"
    ACCEPT Choice
    EVALUATE Choice
        WHEN 1
            PERFORM Add-Record
        WHEN 2
            MOVE 'Y' TO EOF-Switch
    END-EVALUATE.

Add-Record.
    DISPLAY "Enter Employee ID: "
    ACCEPT Temp-EmployeeID
    DISPLAY "Enter Employee Name: "
    ACCEPT Temp-EmployeeName
    DISPLAY "Enter Salary: "
    ACCEPT Temp-Salary
    MOVE Temp-EmployeeID TO EmployeeID
    MOVE Temp-EmployeeName TO EmployeeName
    MOVE Temp-Salary TO Salary
    WRITE EmployeeRecord
    DISPLAY "Record Added Successfully".


Files are specified in the ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
FILE-CONTROL.
    SELECT EmployeeFile ASSIGN TO "EMPLOYEE.DAT"
        ORGANIZATION ...

Where, in this case, ORGANIZATION may be either SEQUENTIAL or LINE SEQUENTIAL depending on use.
All of the clauses:
    LABEL RECORDS STANDARD
    VALUE OF FILE-ID IS "EMPLOYEE.DAT"
    DATA RECORD IS EmployeeRecord

were made obsolete in the COBOL 85 standard and have been removed from later standards and should be removed from this program.
As written, the code will only work for the first record. The statement
    PERFORM Until-Exit

will be done once and will not "loop". Use this instead
    PERFORM Until-Exit UNTIL EOF-Switch = 'Y'

